# jQuery each doesn't have a callback-possibility?

Tags: jquery, loops, callback, each

I have a loop created with each, check this example:

```
$('.foo').each(function(i){
  //do stuff
});
```

Is there any possibility to run a functions when this loop has ended? Couldn't find it on docs or Google.

I can make it work without this kind of solution, but it's always good to search for and use the simpliest methods.

Martti Laine

Comment: What do you mean?  The next statement will execute after the loop has ended.

Comment: It depends on what you are calling in your each loop. You need to add a callback to those (or at least the one you expect to finish last)

Comment: Okay, if you add an answer, which covers your way, I'll choose it.

Comment: what are you doing in your loop?  Are you making asynchronous calls there?  $.each is synchronous, so the next statement will not execute until the function is called on all elements.  If you are doing something asynchronous (like a ajax call or jquery animation) in that function, you will have to write a callback for each one, and then when the last call back occurs, call the next statement.

Comment: I'm making some ajax-calls, but I already figured a way. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoking a jQuery function after .each() has completed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358205/invoking-a-jquery-function-after-each-has-completed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested..

It depends on what you are calling in your each loop. You need to add a callback to those (or at least the one you expect to finish last

Answer (score -1):

This will execute when the loop ends.

```
$('.foo').each(function(i){
  //do stuff
});

$('.foo').//whatever you want to do.
```

Comment: Well, this actually didn't work for me. It immediatly executes the next statement without waiting for the loop to end.