# Callback functions and jQuery's each iterator

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-animate, each

I'm having difficulty calling a callback function after an *each* iterator.

Here's an example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="move.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="ani" style="position:relative; display: inline-block; top:10px; left:0px; width:30px; height:30px; background:#ddd;"></div>
      <div class="ani" style="position:relative; display: inline-block; top:10px; left:110px; width:30px; height:30px; background:#ddd;"></div>
      <div class="ani" style="position:relative; display: inline-block; top:10px; left:210px; width:30px; height:30px; background:#ddd;"></div>
      <div class="ani" style="position:relative; display: inline-block; top:10px; left:310px; width:30px; height:30px; background:#ddd;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $ani = $('div.ani'); 

    var redFlash = function(){
        $ani.eq(0).css('background-color','#e35');
    };

    var goingDown = function(){
        $ani.each(function(i){
            $(this).animate({'top':'100px'}, (i+1)*2000);
        }),redFlash()};

    goingDown();

});
```

The *redFlash* function doesn't get called though.  I've also tried:

```
var goingDown = function(){
    $ani.each(function(i){
        $(this).animate({'top':'100px'}, (i+1)*2000);
    }),function(){
        $ani.eq(0).css('background-color','#e35');
    };
};
```

to no avail.

How can I make redFlash run **after** all the animation inside the *each* iterator has completed?  Is there a way I can make *goingDown* callback to *redFlash* after the animation completes?

Also, does anyone know of any good online resources or books for javascript/jquery callback functions?  The book I have is a little flaky on this topic.

**Edit: Solved using Pointy's pointer on using counters.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$ani = $('div.ani'); 

var redFlash = function(){
$ani.eq(0).css('background-color','#e35');
};

var ani_size = $ani.length-1;
console.debug(ani_size);

var goingDown = function(){
$ani.each(function(i){
    $(this).animate({'top':'100px'}, (i+1)*2000, function(){
    console.debug(i);
    if (i == ani_size){
        redFlash();
    }
    });
});
};
goingDown();

});
```

Comment: Any particular reason why the `redFlash()` call is preceded by a comma instead of a semi-colon?

Comment: When you typed "pyquery" in the question, you meant "jQuery", right?

Comment: I placed a comma there because I thought that's how callback functions were called.

Comment: A callback isn't defined by placing a comma before a function call. Typically when you see a callback, with a comma before it, it's because you're passing the function as an argument in the call to another function. `someFunc( "someArg", callbackFunction )` A function needs to be written to handle a callback function as an argument. It isn't just automatic.

Comment: @patrick ok, it seems clear that each() doesn't work this way.  So how do I incorporate a callback into goingDown()?

Comment: @shafty: I updated my answer with one solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoking a jQuery function after .each() has completed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358205/invoking-a-jquery-function-after-each-has-completed)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is valid, but it won't accomplish what you want.

Do this instead:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mXNz4/2/ *(updated)*

```
$ani = $('div.ani'); 

var redFlash = function(){
    $ani.eq(0).css('background-color','#e35');
}

var goingDown = function(){
    var quantity = $ani.length;
    $ani.each(function(i){
        $(this).animate({'top':'100px'}, (i+1)*2000);
    });
    // schedule redFlash for the end of the last animation
    setTimeout( redFlash, quantity * 2000 );
}

goingDown();
```

Basically, you placed an *immediate* call to `redFlash` *after* the `each()`. An `each()` doesn't have a callback, but the `.animate()` function does so that's where the callback needs to go.

---

**EDIT:** Removed the `+ 600` from the `setTimeout` duration. Didn't make sense.

Comment: No, I want to know how to call redFlash after **all** the animation inside the each iterator has completed.  Your version would call to redFlash straight after the **first** animation.

Comment: @shafty to do that you may want to look into the "Deferred" feature added to jQuery 1.5. Alternatively, you can use your own counter to keep track of which animations have finished.

Comment: @shafty: Yes, I see what you mean. There are a few ways to do it. You can calculate when the last one will fire by getting the quantity of the `ani` elements, multiplying it by `2000`, then using a `setTimeout` so the call is delayed. I'll update

Answer (score 1):

The "id" attribute of each element on a page must be **unique**. You should probably be using the "class" of the elements to characterize them instead of the "id".

Comment: Good point about the IDs. I didn't even bother to look at the HTML. +1