# Fire function after each() has completed

Tags: jquery

this is slightly related to this question
[Invoking a jQuery function after .each() has completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358205/invoking-a-jquery-function-after-each-has-completed)

But the solution doesn't quite seem to work for me.

Basically I have piece of JavaScript that calculates the width of some elements:

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$element.find('li').each(function () {
    totalWidth += $(this).width();
});
```

After this I want to then use the width to set another element:

```
$element.width(totalWidth);
```

If I attach the debugger it works but if I just run it it doesn't. Which makes me think that the width is being set before the `.each()` completes.

I tried using `.promise()` to fix this issue but it doesn't appear to make a difference.

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$element.find('li').each(function () {
    totalWidth += $(this).width();
});

$element.promise().done(function () {
    $element.width(totalWidth);
});
```

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="carousel">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="/Images/Travel2New/Adverts/advertHolder_1.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="/Images/Travel2New/Adverts/advertHolder_2.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="/Images/Travel2New/Adverts/advertHolder_3.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="/Images/Travel2New/Adverts/advertHolder_4.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="/Images/Travel2New/Adverts/advertHolder_5.png" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your width calculation should wait until the graphics is loaded then you can try the following:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var totalWidth = 0;

    $element.find('li').each(function () {
        totalWidth += $(this).width();
    });

    $element.width(totalWidth);
});
```

From [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event example description we can see:

> Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics.
>
> ```
> $(window).load(function () {
>     // run code
> });
> ```

Note that at the moment the `load()` event seems to be [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/), so you should consider the version of jQuery you exploit.

Comment: load() event is deprecated.So do not suggest

Comment: @jhonraymos OK. Any ideas how to replace it?

Comment: http://blog.gabrieleromanato.com/2012/10/jquery-the-load-event-has-been-deprecated-now-what/

Answer (score 2):

well this is the known problem with `.each`

you can do it like this

```
    var totalWidth = 0;

    var $elems = $element.find('li');

    (function fetch(i) {
        if(i >= $elems.length) return;  // no elems left

        var $elem = $elems.eq(i);
        totalWidth += $($elem).width(); 
        if(i+1==$elems.length) 
        {
         $element.width(totalWidth);
        }
        else
        {
         fetch(i + 1);  // next one
        }           
    })(0);  // start with first elem
```