# How to use .promise().done() on $.each json array when done/completed?

Tags: jquery, promise, each

### I want to perform some action when $.each is done.

```
$.each(someArray, function(index, val) {

    //---------some async ajax action here per loop ---------
    $.ajax({...}).done(function(data){...});

}.promise().done(function(){...}); //<-------error here can't use with $.each
```

- Not every **jQuery function** has a `promise()`?
- How do I know when **$.each** array is done?
- Can I change **someArray** to **$someArray** to use it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As you've figured out, `$.each()` doesn't have a `.promise()` so you can't do it the way you were trying to.  Instead, you can use `$.when()` to track when a bunch of promises returned by a group of Ajax functions have all been resolved:

```
var promises = [];
$.each(someArray, function(index, val) {
    //---------some async ajax action here per loop ---------
    promises.push($.ajax({...}).then(function(data){...}));
});
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    // code here when all ajax calls are done
    // you could also process all the results here if you want
    // rather than processing them individually
});
```

Or, rather than your `$.each()`, it's a bit cleaner to use `.map()`:

```
$.when.apply($, someArray.map(function(item) {
    return $.ajax({...}).then(function(data){...});
})).then(function() {
    // all ajax calls done now
});
```

Comment: The .map didnt work for my situation (may be user error) but the promise array worked fantastically. Thanks!! (Sorry Necro but still helped)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know why so many answer on SO mark each().promise().done() as answer like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358205/invoking-a-jquery-function-after-each-has-completed