# jquery $(data).each doesn't work with promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an `each()` loop in my AJAX handler to do push into my `temp` array, but in the end I still get an empty array. It's strange, I remember I once use promise on `each()` so it has no problem.

```
var temp = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/endpoint',
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).each(function() {
            //do some stuff
            console.log(something); // working
            temp.push(something);
    }).promise().done(function() {
        console.log(temp); // still empty array?!
    });
});
```

update: here's how people has done it https://stackoverflow.com/a/8941358/7095330

Comment: There's nothing in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to suggest that `.each` returns a promise

Comment: Maybe it's not a dupe, the OP seems to do strange things with a synchronous loop ?

Comment: What's confusing me is the braces don't match. There are too many closing `}`

Comment: Now that the code is formatted clearly I can see you're missing a `)` to close the `each()`, and the `promise()` call is in the wrong place; it should be on the `$.ajax`, not the `success` handler function

Comment: The code has been changed too much between the really used one and the one pasted here. It doesn't make sense anymore. Maybe the promise is taken on the call to $.ajax in the real code.

Comment: @Liam http://stackoverflow.com/a/8941358/7095330

Comment: But `each` is synchonous, why would you even need a promise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Liam because in my each I have image.onload

Comment: Next time (or this time) please don't forget to include _crucial_ bits of information about what you code does (`image.onload`), and ideally create a snippet, even if broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing your script to what your question is asking, everything seems to be working fine. Hopefully this will help you find out that your problem is somewhere else in your code:

```js
var temp = [];
var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

$(data)
    .each(function(thing) {
      //do some stuff
      console.log(thing); // working
      temp.push(thing);
    })
    .promise()
    .done(function() {
      console.log(temp); // still empty array?!
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However the `promise().done()` is pretty weird; I can't see why you'd need that there.

Sounds like a case for `map`, where you have an input array and you want to transform its contents.

```js
var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

var changedData = data.map(function (datum) {
  // do stuff
  return 'did stuff to ' + datum;
});

console.log(changedData)
```

Unless what you were trying to do was the following, which still works. PEBKAC error perhaps?

```js
var temp = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://google.com/',
    // replaced success: with error:, for example's sake
    error: function(data) {
        $(data).each(function() {
            //do some stuff
            console.log('something');
            temp.push('something');
        }).promise().done(function () {
            console.log('each done', temp);
        });
    },
    done: function() {
        console.log('ajax done:', temp);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't believe there is anything asynchronous about whatever he's doing inside the `success` callback. Wrapping `.each` into a Promise in that context makes no difference than using a purely synchronous alternative. Unless I'm thick right now and am missing something obvious… in which case I'd be happy to know.

Comment: The ops performed before he tries to log `temp` are synchronous as it all happens within the `success` callback.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a bracket }

```
var temp = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '',
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).each(function() {
            //do some stuff
            console.log('something'); // working
            temp.push('something');
    }).promise().done(function() {
        console.log(temp); // still empty array?!
    });
}});
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/gw10un58/